# How to HIDE View when tap on button swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, hidden

**In first view controller we have two buttons**

if we tap on first view controller `oneButn` i need to hide `onebutnContainerView` in secondview controller

if we tap on first view controller `secndButn` i need to hide `twobutnContainerView` in secondview controller

**in first view controller `viewController.oneButnContainerView.isHidden = true` getting error:**

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

**first view controller code:**

```
 class firstViewController: UIViewController{
 @IBAction func oneButn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)

    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewZoomAddressViewController") as! NewZoomAddressViewController;
                viewController.delegate = self

            viewController.oneButnContainerView.isHidden = true
            viewController.twobutnContainerView.isHidden = false

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);

}
@IBAction func secndButn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)

    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewZoomAddressViewController") as! NewZoomAddressViewController;
                viewController.delegate = self

              viewController.oneButnContainerView.isHidden = false

            viewController.twobutnContainerView.isHidden = true

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
 }
}
```

**I have outlets for two views in Second view controller**

```
     @IBOutlet weak var oneButnContainerView: UIView!
     @IBOutlet weak var twoButnContainerView: UIView!
```

how to hide seconviewcontroller view in firstviewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are trying to hide a View that wasn't initialized yet. As a rule of thumb, keep in mind that when you instantiate a viewController, you can only access its data not its views. You have 2 ways of fixing this:

1. Create 2 variables inside secondViewController:

var isOneButnContainerViewHidden: Bool = false
var isTwoButnContainerViewHidden: Bool = false

2. Assign a value to those 2 variables inside firstViewController:

   ```
      let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewZoomAddressViewController") as! NewZoomAddressViewController;
       viewController.delegate = self
       viewController.isOneButnContainerViewHidden= false
       viewController.isTwoButnContainerViewHidden= true
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
   ```
3. Now inside your secondViewController's viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, hide/show your buttonContainerViews based on the value of the 2 variables created:

```
    oneButnContainerView.isHidden = isOneButnContainerViewHidden
    twoButnContainerView.isHidden = isTwoButnContainerViewHidden
```

The second way involves forcing the viewController to layout its views by calling loadViewIfNeeded() on the secondViewController before accessing its views (in this case you are trying to hide/show the views).